# Restart of flink, resulting loss of data in HA mode

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have microservice developed on top of flink layer as base image with ZK as HA. Details as:
Environment:
 `deployed on Kubernetes with Apache flink 1.12.1 version`

Also, i have following configuration with k8s HA:
Job Manager:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  flink-conf.yaml: |
    state.backend: rocksdb
    blob.server.port: 6124
    jobmanager.rpc.address: job-manager
    jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
    parallelism.default: 2
    queryable-state.proxy.ports: 6125
    taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
    jobmanager.memory.process.size: 2900m
    taskmanager.memory.process.size: 2900m
    jobmanager.web.address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.port: 8081
    taskmanager.data.port: 6121
    classloader.resolve-order: parent-first
    state.checkpoints.num-retained: 3
    execution.checkpointing.unaligned: false
    execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints: 2
    execution.checkpointing.interval: 60000
    high-availability: zookeeper
    high-availability.cluster-id: /flink-hs
    high-availability.jobmanager.port: 50010
    high-availability.storageDir:  s3://s3-bucket/zk/
    high-availability.zookeeper.client.acl: open
    high-availability.zookeeper.client.connection-timeout: 3000
    high-availability.zookeeper.client.session-timeout: 3000
    high-availability.zookeeper.client.retry-wait: 5000
    state.checkpoints.dir: s3://s3-bucket/checkpoints/
    state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: s3://s3-bucket/checkpoints/
    s3.path-style: true
    s3.path.style.access: true
  masters: job-manager:8081
```

Task Manager:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  flink-conf.yaml: |
    state.backend: rocksdb
    blob.server.port: 6124
    jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
    queryable-state.proxy.ports: 6125
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 1
    taskmanager.rpc.port: 6122
    jobmanager.memory.process.size: 2900m
    taskmanager.memory.process.size: 2900m
    jobmanager.web.address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.bind-address: 0.0.0.0
    rest.port: 8081
    taskmanager.data.port: 6121
    classloader.resolve-order: parent-first
    state.checkpoints.num-retained: 3
    execution.checkpointing.unaligned: false
    execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints: 2
    execution.checkpointing.interval: 60000
    high-availability: zookeeper
    high-availability.cluster-id: /flink-hs
    high-availability.jobmanager.port: 50010
    high-availability.storageDir:  s3://s3-bucket/zk/
    high-availability.zookeeper.client.acl: open
    high-availability.zookeeper.client.connection-timeout: 3000
    high-availability.zookeeper.client.session-timeout: 3000
    high-availability.zookeeper.client.retry-wait: 5000
    state.checkpoints.dir: s3://s3-bucket/checkpoints/
    state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: s3://s3-bucket/checkpoints/
    s3.path-style: true
    s3.path.style.access: true
  masters: job-manager:8081
```

Whenever i get following exception, job manager(JM) crashes. And once it is crashed, checkpoints restarts from 1, instead of from last # of checkpoint.

```
org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: JobManager responsible for 00000000000000000000000000000000 lost the leadership.
...
...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: ResourceManager leader changed to new address null
```

Also, i have TTL configured as follows:

```
final static String TTL = 45;
public static final StateTtlConfig ttlConfig = StateTtlConfig
            .newBuilder(Time.days(Integer.parseInt(TTL)))
            .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnCreateAndWrite)
            .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
            .build();
```

To add, i have developed a streaming application which will be reading from kafka topic.

Can somebody suggest, why my state is getting lost when i encountered above exception.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you use stateful IP addrees for your k8s pod? Because your exception suggests a null address upon restart `ResourceManager leader changed to new address null`.

Comment: No, we do not use stateful IP address for k8s pod for job and task manager.

Comment: According to this thread https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg39194.html it could be ZK exception or timeout